# Не могу получить картинку, через роутер

Tags: phalcon, router, response

Не могу получить картинку через роутер. PHP, Phalcon, база данных монго. Весь проект лежит на  https://bitbucket.org/lcasper01/szji/src/master/

Вот роутер
`$router->add( '/camera_photo/{image_id}', 'Image::getImage' )->via( [ 'GET' ] );`

Контроллер app\controllers\ImageController.php

```
public function getImageAction()
  {
    $this->view->setRenderLevel(\Phalcon\Mvc\View::LEVEL_NO_RENDER);
    $img_id = $this->dispatcher->getParam( 'image_id' );
    $image=image::findById($img_id);
    $this->response->resetHeaders();
    $this->response->setStatusCode(200, 'OK');
    $this->response->setContentLength($image->size);
    $this->response->setContentType($image->mime);
    $content = $image->picture->getData();
    $this->response->setContent($content);
    return $this->response->send();
  }
```

Comment: Выводит страницу с черным фоном

Comment: имя модели с маленькой буквы. нужно с большой

Answer (score 0):

Вангую, что дело в методе `getData()`. Проверь установлено ли расширение `php-mbstring` (`php7.2-mbstring`) и установлен ли пакет `phalcon/incubator` в Composer'e. Если установлен, то подключен ли autoload в `/app/index.php`